# Is there a better way to call and place this click handler function?

Tags: javascript

I have a draw function whose purpose is to provide elements' movements and interactivity. In this function, I place an Event Listener for clicks.

[image]

***How is supposed to work this Event Listener?***

When pushed, the event listener gets the x and y values of the point where it was clicked, and, the elements (circles) 100 pixels far from the clicked point
change their color to white.

Although it works, it only considers the first elements of the array.  I tried to see if it was because of the counter initialization, but it seems it's not.

Note: I am using an array called "strip[]".

```
//7.EVENT LISTENER- 

rect.node.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
    mouseState = true;
    console.log("Got you!");
    counter = 0;
    counter++;

    //Determine the distance beetween two points with simple equation:         
    dist = distance(ev.offsetX, ev.offsetY, strip[counter].xpos, strip[counter].ypos);

    //SHOW DISTANCE   
    console.log("bombayah! " + dist);
    console.log("disk:" + counter);

    //7. PRINT THE MESSAGE  AND CHANGE COLOR  
    if (dist > 100) {
        console.log(">100- MAYOR");
        strip[counter].attr({
            "fill": "white",
            "stroke-width": 0
        });
    }
    if (dist < 100 || mouseState != true) {
        console.log("<100 MENOR");
        strip[counter].attr({
            "fill": colorString,
            "stroke-width": 0
        });
    }
    //******************************************* 
});

rect.node.addEventListener('mouseup', function(ev) {
    mouseState = false;
    console.log("Up!")
});
```

Comment: Are you asking how to check the position of all array elements? This doesn't seem to have anything to do with the click event.

Comment: No. The function is supposed to change the color of all elements 100px within the point where you clicked, which means that is the ball number 1,2 and 3 are 100px or fewer pixels far from that point, their color will change to white. But it only works with one ball, which is the first element of the array .